# How do I copy and paste text that's in a weird window (pictured here)?

Tags: x11, copy-paste

[image]

The program is called ncview. I can drag and highlight the text inside, but not even Ctrl-C allows the text to be copied for pasting. Current distribution is a Debian distribution.

Comment: After selecting, Shift-Insert or middle click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting text should put that text in your primary selection buffer; this means you may be able to middle-click to paste it into another window.